# Add p:blockUI in p:menu without items

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, menu

I would like add a `p:blockUI` component in a `p:menu`.
My xhtml file is this:

```
    <h:form id="form">

    <p:menu id="menu" 
            model="#{beanBacking.model}">

            <p:blockUI
                block="menu" 
                trigger="menu" >
                <img src="images/ajaxloading.gif" />
            </p:blockUI>                

    </p:menu>

</h:form>
```

Waiting blockUI doesn't appear.
I must add blockUI compulsorily only with Primefaces dataTable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take it out of the `<p:menu>`.

Comment: already tried, nothing.

Comment: Will then probably need to attach Java code way as you are constructing the menu using Java code.

Comment: Doing like this using plain XHTML works - `<p:blockUI block="menu" trigger="menu" widgetVar="widget" ...>...</p:blockUI>` `<p:submenu label="Item"><p:menuitem actionListener="#{bean.listener}" onstart="PF('widget').show()" oncomplete="PF('widget').hide()" value="Item"/></p:submenu>`.

Comment: My bean creates an instance of MenuModel: model = new DefaultMenuModel(); and populating with information database. I believe that blockUI can be used only on particular components...

Comment: You will need to attache a `<p:blockUI>` to every child `<p:submenu>` of `<p:menu>` using Java code as said earlier, since you are constructing the menu using Java code.